# Most efficient way of counting relationships

Tags: sql, database

So for example, if you had a users table, and a friends mapper between users. Should you add an extra column in users called 'friends-count' and update it every time they add a friend, or should you just do a count query every time you need the count. Which one is more efficient?

Comment: If only talking about performance, it's faster to read from a single field than doing a count on another table. Though that approach will require more work each time a user adds a friends or removes one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you have two versions of the truth and what would you do if they got out of sync... And how would you determine that.

The most efficient eay is to count each time, the support and validation effort the maintain a cache are likely to outweigh any computational benefit. CPU cycles are cheap compared to effort from devs.

If it ends up being a bottleneck in your app then look at caching, you then have a tangible benefit for the caching.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. So it's more of a consistency problem.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. It's not always true as joocer said that the more efficient option is to count every time.

That may be true when your system has relationship information about not many people queried with a frequency that allows a query to return results before the next query comes (the limits depends on your architecture efficiency). I mean if you can count friendships in 1 second and you get 10 counting requests at the second your system will collapse shortly.

A counting action, for each request, on a system big and frequently queried as "Facebook" for example is not really efficient.

Concurrency on counting field can be handled through many advanced techniques (by the middle tier, by the front end or even by the database depending on your preferences for each architecture) with no much over-work for the system, that doesn't depend a lot by the database size.

If you'll say more details about you architecture, you can get better answer for your specific case.

Caching is a similar way to say store counting on an extra column (eg. database materialized view, witch I tend to suggest you, if your RDBMS supports it ). Depending on the caching implementation, it usually tends to be less efficient than storing directly the extra information on the RDBMS in an optimal way.

Comment: Was talking more wholistically, unless your data has a lot of updates, of course it's quicker to just read a single value in a single row. But the associated effort to do this right isn't to be ignored, as is probably more than expected.